# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With regard to a data import on which I have to do simple operations, I encounter the following error with the iloc function. What can I do? Thanks

```
  List_of_X=pd.read_csv('List_of_X.csv')

   def main_function(self, i, j, test1, test2, test3, test4=None, test5=None, data_type=None):

       for x in range(0, len(self.List_of_X)):
   
           old_values_X = self.old_X()[i]
           new_values_X = self.List_of_X.iloc[x][1].astype('float')[j]
```

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable (on new_values_X line)

I report the data sample:

```
name    | X | Y |
red     |1.5| 2 |
yellow  |5  | 3 |
blue    |3  | 4 |
```

Comment: What's self.old_X() function? Or is the main_function inside a class?

Comment: self.old_X() is a function from another file to read the old values of the Xs. So, it is recalled inside a class. Thank you

Comment: And what is `i`?

Comment: you have not provided sample data but seems like `List_of_X.iloc[x][1]` is a scalar value and referencing index [j] to that value is inavlid

Comment: @asnerdyasSteveWozniak i it's an index to create a list and associate values

Comment: @eshirvana thank you but id doesn't work. The .csv file is composed by 3 columns and I want to extract data from the 2 column, so for [x][1]...it still doesn't work

Comment: you have to provide sample data and a piece of code that we can reproduce the problem ,

Comment: ok I'll add on the question

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, reproduceable example. We can't see the definitions of your properties, or methods, and so it's hard to understand what's going on for us.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the second declaration as:

```
       new_values_X = self.List_of_X.iloc[x][1].astype('float')
```

was not a value indexable